# CMake Library not linking correctly

Tags: c++, c, linker, cmake, linker-errors

I am attempting to write a program that uses the [BNO055 Driver](https://github.com/BoschSensortec/BNO055_driver). I have tried many different methods of linking this library to my project.

Since the BNO055 driver does not come with any build system setup or library built I have to include the driver in some fashion.

For each of the following attempts I get the build error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable imc-server
CMakeFiles/imc-server.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `bno055_read_data()':
/home/noah/Documents/Inertial-Motion-Capture/imc-server/main.cpp:83: undefined reference to `bno055_init(bno055_t*)'
/home/noah/Documents/Inertial-Motion-Capture/imc-server/main.cpp:84: undefined reference to `bno055_set_power_mode(unsigned char)'
/home/noah/Documents/Inertial-Motion-Capture/imc-server/main.cpp:86: undefined reference to `bno055_set_operation_mode(unsigned char)'
/home/noah/Documents/Inertial-Motion-Capture/imc-server/main.cpp:91: undefined reference to `bno055_read_quaternion_wxyz(bno055_quaternion_t*)'
/home/noah/Documents/Inertial-Motion-Capture/imc-server/main.cpp:97: undefined reference to `bno055_read_linear_accel_xyz(bno055_linear_accel_t*)'
/home/noah/Documents/Inertial-Motion-Capture/imc-server/main.cpp:98: undefined reference to `bno055_convert_double_linear_accel_xyz_msq(bno055_linear_accel_double_t*)'
/home/noah/Documents/Inertial-Motion-Capture/imc-server/main.cpp:101: undefined reference to `bno055_set_power_mode(unsigned char)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [imc-server] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/imc-server.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is the kind of error I usually see when a library has not been linked properly.

**Attempt 1** - *Include the BNO055 driver source*
I first tried to go with a simple approach and just include the driver source(`bno055.h` and `bno055.c`) in my executable:

```
#CMakeLists.txt
set(SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES}
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bno055/bno055.h
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bno055/bno055.c)

[...]

set(SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES}
        main.cpp)

add_executable(imc-server ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

**Attempt 2** - *Build library file out of driver source and link*
Later on I tried building a library for the BNO055 driver and then linking it to my executable:

```
#In BNO055 sub-directory CMakeLists.txt
add_library(bno055 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bno055.c)
target_include_directories(bno055 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})


#In Main CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(bno055)

[...]

add_executable(imc-server main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(imc-server bno055)
```

Both of these attempts failed, and as far as I know they should have properly linked. This leads me to believe that either
a) I am linking the BNO055 library incorrectly
or
b) I have to do something special to allow the BNO055 Driver to work with my program

I have looked at many other SO questions related to the build error I am getting and so far all of the solution I have found do not help.

**Links**
[Project Github Repo](https://github.com/Noah-Huppert/Inertial-Motion-Capture)(Code under `/imc-server`)
- [Commit `39a6196`, Attempt 1](https://github.com/Noah-Huppert/Inertial-Motion-Capture/tree/39a6196e48623c76323b92d37bf6e811c22f3ad5)
- [Commit `e64e7c8`, Attempt 2](https://github.com/Noah-Huppert/Inertial-Motion-Capture/tree/e64e7c87242e3887252ed85a025561d5985d10b3)
[BNO055 Driver](https://github.com/BoschSensortec/BNO055_driver)

Comment: You are including C header into C++ source without `extern "C" { }` wrapper. I guess, this is the cause.

Comment: @arrowd It worked, Thanks! If you want, put that as the answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including C header into C++ source without wrapping it into `extern "C" { }` block. The driver code is compiled as C, because CMake selects compiling mode by file extension.

Answer (score 0):

build .c and .cpp without `extern "C" {}`

change main.cpp to main.c, you get rid of this problem

```
set(SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES}
    main.c)
```